# Coldfusion Button to Save a Value to a Variable

Tags: button, coldfusion

I have a button in Coldfusion:

```
<cfinput name="Accept" type="button" value="Acknowledge"
    onclick="ColdFusion.Window.hide('my_alert')">
```

Currently the button, when clicked, hides the alert window. I'd also like the button to set my variable var1 to YES. Is there anyway I can add that to onclick? How would I go about doing that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to set a javascript variable? If so, use ColdFusion.Window.onHide() function, like so:

```
<script>
function onHideWindow(name) {
   var1 = "yes";
}

function hideWindow() {
   ColdFusion.Window.onHide('my_alert', onHideWindow);
   ColdFusion.Window.hide('my_alert');
}
</script>
...
<cfinput name="Accept" type="button" value="Acknowledge" onclick="hideWindow()">
```

Comment: It's actually a coldfusion parameter. Can I do that?

Comment: if it's a page/request variable - then no: by the time your page loads all cf code is already processed into html. if it's a persistent scope var (session var, for example) the you could make an ajax call to a remote cfc method which could change a session var.

Comment: Thanks, I'll switch directions and try that.